# geometric patterns in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have been challenge to recreate the image below using HTML/CSS/JS without using any img files. I was thinking that I could make the shapes with  and CSS but I know this is probably the most stupid way to do it.

Do any of you have suggestions how to approach this? Maybe a HTML5 canvas? I see the pattern is made of two layers, one with triangles and the top layer with circles. How would I approach this if I wanted to have the triangles and the circles randomly generated?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: I'd say this is a perfect task for canvas. Just use a for loop to create all the triangles and then  another for loop for all the circles. Triangles and circles are both in their own grid, so you don't have to worry about overlapping stuff

Comment: You're entirely correct in all of your assumptions. HTML5 canvas, two layers, randomly generate each using javascript. Really you aren't asking a question at all, you're looking for confirmation that you're on the right track. And you are :)

Comment: You can make a circle and a triangle in HTML and CSS. Once you get them set its just a copy and paste with lots of positioning css

Comment: @Andrew ... a lot of copy and paste... its easier, and less messy,  to use a canvas.

Comment: Just giving another option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could definitely achieve this by using the canvas element, but have you thought about using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) ?

D3.js is a library which is capable of manipulating documents based on data.
Since all the elements within your picture have an exact position within a cartesian coordinate system you would just have to provide the data and then it would be fairly simple to append the elements to your document.

You could be very precise by using the exact coordinates of each element. Take a look at the snippet and i am sure you will get the idea. The D3 way of selecting an manipulating elements is very similar to what jQuery does, so if you are familiar with jQuery you will like D3js.

Hope this helps you out.

```js
var margin        = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}, 
    w             = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h             = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    circleRadii   = 15,
    triData       = [{x: 20, y: 30}, {x: 50, y: 120}, {x: 140, y: 160}],
    circleData    = [{x: 10, y: 10}, {x: 40, y: 80}, {x: 160, y: 70}];

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.left + margin.right)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var tri =  svg.selectAll(".point")
             .data(triData)
             .enter().append("path")
             .attr("class", "point")
             .attr("stroke", "none")
             .attr("fill", "rgba(30,110,160,.5)")
             .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(1024*2))
             .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(circleData)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle");

var circleAttr = circles
                    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                    .attr("r", circleRadii)
                    .style("fill", "rgba(10,100,0,.5)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks David, Checking out D3 now. Seems like it could be the best tool for the job.